# Flexbox not working in Edge and FireFox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular6

I know that this is similar to https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/108 but I have a different scenario and the answers in that issue doesn't really solve my problem. I'm trying to make a page with a sticky header and footer with a scrollable content. It works perfectly on Chrome but the header & footer don't work when using Edge and Firefox. I have two nested elements for the content. The innermost is an overflow. As I've said, it works perfectly in Chrome and IE but not in Edge & Firefox. I tried removing the outer content element and now it's working in Edge & Mozilla but the problems goes back to Chrome. Could someone help me with this issue? I've been fixing this issue for weeks now. Thanks! Here's the stackblitz to for replication: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksjqak
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I already found a solution by setting the min-height of the outer content element to 0.
[image]